# Stubbing a checked exception: how to handle the exception

Tags: java, junit, junit4, mockito, stub

I am using Junit 4 and Mockito and I want to stub a method call so that it throws an exception:

```
doThrow(MyException.class).when(myObject).foo();
```

The problem is, MyException is a checked exception, so the call to `foo()` in this statement causes the compiler to complain that I must either handle the exception or add a throws clause to my method.

So I am wondering what the right way to handle this situation is?  My thoughts so far have been:

1. I am using it wrong and there is a better way to do it.
2. I just add `throws MyException` to the test method
3. I extract the call out to another method that just swallows the exception

e.g.

```
private void givenFooThrowsAnException(MyObject myObject) {
    try {
        doThrow(MyException.class).when(myObject).foo();
    } catch (MyException e) {
        // Required to stub a checked exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the signature of foo() method, is it supposed to throw a checked exception? if not you are using it wrong. throw a runtimeException instead inyour test.

Comment: I would go with option #2. There is nothing wrong adding throws Exception to a test method?

Comment: myObject is a dependency that I am injecting into the class under test. I am testing the two paths taken by the class under test, one of which occurs when myObject.foo() throws MyException, which is a checked exception. Maybe I am misunderstanding your point, but my problem isn't with the fact I am saying doThrow(MyException.class), but that the compiler sees a call to foo() here, which throws an exception that must be handled. But since this is just setting up a stub the exception isn't actually going to be thrown.

Comment: So, if the exception is thrown, something is going seriously wrong, and you would like your test to fail. So add `throws MyException` clause to your test method signature, and let JUnit make the test fail if the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the stubbing forces you to handle the checked exception, it will actually never throw that exception. The most elegant approach is to declare the test method to throw that exception.

There is only one caveat with that approach. If your test actually verifies that the checked exception is thrown by declaring it in the `@Test` annotation.

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void test...() throws MyException {
    //...
}
```

In that case if your stubbing gets messed up and does throw the checked exception, it may yield a passing test that probably should have failed.

Alternatively you could simply [use unchecked exceptions](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/why-should-you-use-unchecked-exceptions.html).